# Is angularJS an alternative to JSF?

Tags: jsf-2, angularjs

I was looking for a webframework to use in an application for a call center. 3 important requirements would probably be

1. an ability for a quick, localized refresh of the screen
2. a need to collect information from 3-4 disparate systems
3. the roadmap/longevity of the framework itself

Was looking at JSF & AngularJS (I have worked on neither). Am I right in considering them as alternatives or are they meant for very different things. How do these measure against the 3 considerations above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, angular is clearly not an alternative to JSF. JSF is a server side java application framework (with some ajax features). Angular is a client side javascript framework. It's a bit like comparing JQuery and JSPs.

Comment: Thanks. In your opinions can we use either of the 2 frameworks to similar things ? In my case my primary requirement would be to collect data from disparate systems. In fact I am thinking I might need to show some of the windows of the other applications as is in a single view.

Comment: Can we used them both inside the same view ?